# Determine if NHibernate Session is in an error state

Tags: .net, winforms, nhibernate

All,

Is it possible to determine from the session object (ISession, or its ISessionImplementor) if an error occured? Or, is it possible to hook up an even handler that is invoked when an error occurs on a session?

I am well aware of the pattern for dealing w/ sessions by wrapping your code in try/catch and disposing the session immediately. In my case though, I have implemented something equivalent to session scope that hands out hibernate session to my DAOs that run in the current scope. When I give out the hibernate session, the client code uses it simply to run a persistent operation and I don't want the client to be responsible for doing session clean-up,- that is the responsibility of the session scope. Here's example:

```
using (new SessionScope(SessionHelper.OpenSession()))
{
    // do read/write etc.
    // ex:
    mydao.MakePersistent(someEntity);  // <-- an error can occur here
} // implicit flush/clean up, BUT in order to do this correctly I have to know if the session in the scope has no errors!
```

As you can see, the SessionScope implements IDisposable and there I do session finalization like flush, tx.Commit(), and disposal. But, I can't flush a session if an error occured on it!

One work around is not to give out the raw hibernate session, but a wrapper object w/ methods for executing session operations, that way I can wrap any operation in try/catch and know when the error occured. If you ask me, that is silly workaround.

The other option is that all DAOs inform my session scope that an error occured,- this means that all my DAO methods (in the catch block) must check if session scope is defined, and if it is, they are responsible for failing the session (scope.FailSession(session);) That's much better but I have to do it religiously in all my DAO and if I forget, my session scope will misbehave by calling session.Flush() on an errored session.

Thanks to Oskar B. comment it is required to use a transaction based approach for any logic that needs to have ACID properties or is at risk of an exception that may not relate to persistence. Here's revised solution:

```
using (var txScope = new TransactionScope(SessionHelper.OpenSession()))
{
     Customer cust = mydao.getCustomer();
     Order order = mydao.getOrder(cust);
     // modify order, etc. (an error may occur at any time within this scope)
     txScope.VoteCommit();           
} // if we voted commit, it will flush/commit otherwise it will rollback
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the only way is to handle the exception and deal w/ it.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would have the transaction separate from the session, since often we want the application code to confirm transaction commit (by reaching the line tx.Commit() in the absence of an exception). The session scope's Dispose() then becomes simply session.Dispose().

One way is to simply replace your idea of scope.FailSession() with scope.CompleteSession(). This is analogous to the above - if you forget it nothing will be saved and the problem will be immediately apparent.

Often, we handle the session on a much larger scope - not in a particular DAO, as this makes it difficult to perform the entire work of "user request" within a single transaction. Typically when an exception occurs, it will lead to the rest of the domain logic and other "application code" being skipped. So the actual exception handling and session handling need only be present in a few parts of the code.

Comment: Thx for your contribution. I am not sure if I was clear, but defining session scope above can span more than just a method call, for example in web scenario this could span single web request. My dao base class has a session property that is inherited by all DAOs. The session property simply return hibernate session for dao's current scope.

Comment: I decided to go w/ the idea of FailSession() after all for 2 reasons: 1) I already have a catch block  to catch hibernate exception and re-throw it as PersistenceException (therefore my app doesn't reference hibernate) 2) I find the method explicit name more descriptive on my intentions and leave the using stmt to either commit/rollback based on whether I failed session or not

Comment: What happens if an exception occurs someplace else? Will you then still commit a half-completed transaction?

Comment: Then it's unrelated and no, never commit something that part succeeded. Inside my DAO, with try{ Persist(model); } catch (HibernateException e) { FailSession(sess); throw new PersistenceException(e); } I only catch persistent exceptions. Any other exception will cause default clean up behaviour on the session which simply is Rollback().

Comment: Actually, that's a good point,- currently all my operations are single tasks so that it either they succeed or fail, or are simply reading the datastore. W/ reads, it just doesn't matter, but w/ longer transactions where you persist items at different times, it does. At that point the correct thing would be to follow ACID.

Comment: A really quick and dirty solution would be to change the code in DAOs to this: try{ Persist(model); } catch { FailSession(sess); throw; } But that's not neccessarly correct or efficient.

Comment: Actually, the above quick/dirty solution will not work since the exception can occur elsewhere (outside the DAO) in the session scope. The only correct thing would be to have a try/catch inside my current session scope and decide EXPLICITLY to whether do rollback or commit.

Comment: Well... like I initially stated, many have come to the conclusion that the safest way to handle this is to have the transaction management explicitly commit only if no unhandled exception has occurred within the unit-of-work. The FailSession() is an interesting concept for when you must catch the exception and for some reason not rethrow it. (I.e. it would report a failing error without using an exception.) Though I must say, I haven't found a need for this so far.

Comment: The FailSession() is a hibernate thing and was ONLY designed for the purpose of using it w/ a 'simple' session scope. When the session scope went out of scope, it either flushed/committed the session or if it was informed that the session was bad by scope.FailSession() then it would rollback. The code that would throw was in DAOs only, and therefore would catch, fail session, rethrow,- simply doing property assignment on entities in a given scope in my case will/should never throw.